# Calculate daily mean of data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r that contains readings each five minutes of an hour for couple of months. I want to calculate daily mean of the var3 (data frame under) and add into this data frame as var4.

Here is my df:

```
>df
         timestamp           Var1         Var2        Var3 
1    2018-07-20 13:50:00   32.0358        28.1        3.6       
2    2018-07-20 13:55:00   32.0358        28.0        2.5       
3    2018-07-20 14:00:00   32.0358        28.1        2.2
```

I find this solution from searching the forum, but it's raising error.

Here is the solution  I am applying:

```
aggregate(ts(df$var3[, 2], freq = 288), 1, mean)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error in df$var3[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I think this should work for my data frame too but not able to remove this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  group_by(Day = day(ymd_hms(timestamp))) %>%
  mutate(Var4 = mean(Var3))
## A tibble: 1,000 x 6
## Groups:   Day [5]
#   timestamp            Var1  Var2  Var3   Day  Var4
#   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 2018-07-20 13:55:30  32.2  22.9  2.35    20  2.99
# 2 2018-07-20 14:00:30  37.7  24.8  2.99    20  2.99
# 3 2018-07-20 14:05:30  38.7  29.6  3.47    20  2.99
# 4 2018-07-20 14:10:30  30.4  24.2  3.02    20  2.99
# 5 2018-07-20 14:15:30  32.0  28.4  2.95    20  2.99
## … with 995 more rows
```

**Sample Data**

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = ymd_hms("2018-07-20 13:50:30") + 60*5 * 1:1000,
                   Var1 = runif(100,30,40),
                   Var2 = runif(100,20,30),
                   Var3 = runif(100,2,4))
```